# Storing std map in map

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, std

I have to store std::map as value in std::map

```
std::map< std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > someStorage;
```

How to insert into second(inner) map? I tried with:

```
someStorage.insert( std::make_pair("key", std::make_pair("key2", "value2")) );
```

But this throws a lot of errors. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you [edit] to be more specific than "throws a lot of errors"?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try:

```
std::map< std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > someStorage;

someStorage["Hi"]["This Is Layer Two"] = "Value";
```

Comment: That is needlessly EXPENSIVE as it creates a default string then reassigns it to the value passed in. Best approach is how Dark Falcon has done it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479017/storing-std-map-in-map/4479026#4479026  - I think you're getting voted-up these days only because of your accrued points and not the quality of your answers. I wish people would take the time to read/think about your answers.

Comment: I like my answer because it is the easiest to read. Expense is rarely a factor, **maintainability** is a real cost. This code is the easiest to maintain. PS. Also copying a string is about as expensive as copying a couple of integers (as `most` std::string implementations uses a copy on write approach and thus the string is not actually copied).

Comment: @Oxsnarder: What is the cost of creating a default string and then assigning a `char const*` to it ? The default `std::string` probably performance no memory allocation (if yours does, shoot off your library provider), and then there is `std::string& std::string::operator=(char const*)`, and of course if the string already exists, then you avoid building a temporary `std::string` that won't get inserted anyway... **I** think that you're being needlessly snappy these days.

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in the fight going on here -- but bear in mind that your answer above is not semantically equivalent to `insert` in that it will overwrite a value which is already there whereas `insert` will not. Which is preferable depends on context, of course -- but the original question in this case does seem to ask for `insert`.

Comment: @Martin: Indeed -- unlike the case in point, what I said and what you said *are* semantically equivalent :)

Comment: @Stuart Golodetz: To rephrase: insert() will not change the value if it already exists, while the above code will change the value. (As translated from PhDish into English for the rest of us).  :-)

Comment: @Martin: Touché ;) I guess the tricky bit was "is not semantically equivalent to", which translates to "does not have the same meaning as". Apologies for talking in weird PhD tongues :-)

Comment: @Martin: Removed, sorry -- no offence intended. Was just curious when you said was all.

Comment: @Gracchus: The performance hit was negligible at best with C++03. With C++11 and move semantics its even less relvant. The thing you need to think about now is weather to use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 29):

```
someStorage["key"].insert(std::make_pair("key2", "value2")));
```

If you still wanted to use insert on the outer map as well, here is one way to do it

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> inner;
inner.insert(std::make_pair("key2", "value2"));
someStorage.insert(std::make_pair("key", inner));
```

Comment: That alone won't cut it. Where is the map in the value created?

Comment: You do realize that someStorage["key"] does an insert if required, using a default-initialized value? (in other words, an empty map is associated with the key if the key does not exist)

Comment: You should not use make_pair. You are assuming that the implementation uses pair. Use `std::map<Key, Value>::value_type` it is typedefed for exactly that reason.

Comment: On the contrary: The C++0x standard says: "For a map<Key,T> the key_type is Key and the value_type is pair<const
Key,T>." (23.4.1.2)

Comment: @Dark Falcon: Yes exactly. Which is why you should use value_type and not make_pair.

Comment: @Martin: The bit he quoted is in essence a specific guarantee from the standard that the two are equivalent. In other words, `make_pair` is always guaranteed to work here (and for what it's worth, it's the idiomatic usage when doing an `insert` in my experience).

Comment: @Stuart Golodetz: @Dark Falcon: Yes. I understand that. But what do you think the type returned by make_pair is? As a hint its not the same as value_type because "key1", "key2", "value2" are not std::strings! You are lucking out on a couple of implicit conversions. By using value_type you are getting the correct type without having to worry about the compiler doing any implicit conversions. In my team (probably company wide): make_pair is removed at code review time. Here value_type is idiomatic (because it is the type stored in the map).

Comment: @Martin: I'm aware that there are implicit conversions going on -- they're desirable from my perspective, because code with `make_pair` can often be more readable. If they're causing you a performance problem (you profiled, I assume), then sure, it's fair enough to use `value_type`. But otherwise I don't see a major benefit. Suppose your map is `std::map<VeryLongKeyTypeName,VeryLongValueTypeName> m;`, you'd certainly want to avoid writing `m.insert(std::map<VLKTN,VLVTN>::value_type(k,v));` when you could write `m.insert(std::make_pair(k,v));` -- the latter's much clearer.

Comment: I accept that you could use a `typedef`, but that's extra hassle for what is in most cases little to no benefit. And if your map type depends on template parameters, then you end up having to add `typename` before `std::map<K,V>::value_type` each time. You could do `typedef typename std::map<K,V>::value_type MapVal;` and then `m.insert(MapVal(k,v));`, sure, but I don't see the real advantage.

Comment: I would have done: `typedef std::map<VeryLongKeyTypeName,VeryLongValueTypeName> Storage;` Then its `m.insert(Storage::value_type(key,value));` Which is much cleaner and more readable. The cost of the implicit conversions is not the point (I am sure the compiler optimizations would make it practically the same). The implicit conversion is problematic as it is not always obvious what is happening (you happen to get lucky in the std::string is very well tested in this regards, any other user defined type I would be much more suspicious of what is happening (and thus need to spend time checking)).

Comment: The problem here is not when you first write it. Because you know how all your code is working. But the problem comes from maintaining the code. If any types are changed (and this happens a lot) the implicit conversions can start causing massive problems. For Example Key1 is change from a std::string into Application::Key1 this type change will cascade through the program. Using the correct type the first time will prevent problems. Using make_pair with all the associated (extra type conversions (there will always be some but try and minimiz)) will require a lot more verification.

Comment: @Martin: If e.g. `VeryLongKeyTypeName` was a template parameter, it would end up being `typename Storage::value_type(key, value)` of course, because `value_type` would still be a dependent type. (Just deciding how to reply to the rest, bear with me... :))

Comment: As far as implicit conversions go, it strikes me that the true problem lies with people who allow implicit conversions that they shouldn't. By default, I'd tend to make most single-parameter constructors `explicit` unless I was specifically intending to allow the implicit conversion. (I'd also aim to avoid unwise conversion operators, e.g. providing `operator const char*` for a string type.) If only sensible implicit conversions are supported, I don't see why there should be a major problem.

Comment: I think the bottom line is that I don't think it makes a vast amount of difference -- the `value_type` way potentially involves an otherwise unneeded `typedef`, and is a bit more hassle, but makes the types involved more explicit. The `make_pair` way is a bit more convenient. If used properly, I don't think either should cause real problems. (I have changed key types of maps before, and I've never had a problem with implicit conversions.) YMMV - I guess I wouldn't have a major problem with using `value_type` if I worked in one of your teams, but I don't think it really buys you very much.

Comment: @Stuart Golodetz: Well though out arguments. Good luck with the viva.

Comment: @DarkFalcon , How would one construct a map consisting of both primitive values and map inside a map, some thing like the below

    {
      'Key1': '1',
      'Key2': {
        'a' : '2',
        'b' : '3',
        'c' : {
          'd' : '3',
          'e' : '1'
          }
        }
    }

Answer (score 4):

A map has a insert method that accepts a key/value pair. Your key is of type string, so that's no problem, but your value is *not* of type pair (which you generate) but of type map. So you either need to store a complete map as your value *or* you change the initial map definition to accept a pair as value.

Answer (score 4):

**//Try this:**

```
std::map< std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > myMap;

myMap["key one"]["Key Two"] = "Value";
myMap["Hello"]["my name is"] = "Value";
```

**//To print the map:**

```
for( map<string,map<string,string> >::const_iterator ptr=myMap.begin();ptr!=myMap.end(); ptr++) {
    cout << ptr->first << "\n";
    for( map<string,string>::const_iterator eptr=ptr->second.begin();eptr!=ptr->second.end(); eptr++){
        cout << eptr->first << " " << eptr->second << endl;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use list initialization:

```
someStorage.insert( std::make_pair("key", std::map<std::string, std::string> {std::make_pair("key2", "value2")}) );
```